# Show image while inner html is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a gif image while the page is loading using javascript. What am i doing wrong ? :/

```
$("#basicReport").click(function() {
    $('#loader').html('');
    $("#loade").show();
    $("#loader").load("BasicReports.php", function () {
        $("#loade").hide();
    });
});
```

and i have the div here :

```
<div id="loader" class = "paddleft" >
<div id="loade"> <img id="" align="center" src="load.gif"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing as far as I can see. What happens?

Comment: what's the problem with the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the gif container out of `#loader` because you're destroying the gif when you do `.html('')`:

```
<div id="loade"> <img id="" align="center" src="load.gif"></div>
<div id="loader" class = "paddleft" >

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#loader').html('');
```

remove this  .html has remove #loader tag